# set directory does not work for TemporaryFile

Tags: numpy

I am trying to use TemporaryFile. here is the code snippet.

```
from tempfile import TemporaryFile
outfile = TemporaryFile(dir='./')
np.save(outfile, np.arange(9))
outfile.close()
```

I print outfile.name, then I got 62, I didn't find anything with a name 62. Actually I got nothing in specified directory.

My question is, where does TemporaryFile save file, and how to specify a directory for TemporaryFile() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want `NamedTemporaryFile` instead of `TemporaryFile`. `TemporaryFile` can be created in such a way as to not be visible on the normal filesystem, whereas  `NamedTemporaryFile` is guaranteed to be visible.

From [the `NamedTemporaryFile` docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile):

> This function operates exactly as `TemporaryFile()` does, except that the file is guaranteed to have a visible name in the file system (on Unix, the directory entry is not unlinked). That name can be retrieved from the name attribute of the returned file-like object...

So just replace all mentions of `TemporaryFile` in your code with `NamedTemporaryFile` and then everything should work like you expect. Be aware though that a `NamedTemporaryFile` will still be removed from your filesystem once you `close()` it.